# Dispatch messages in message queue individually

Tags: android, thread-safety, message-queue

Is it possible to dispatch each queued messages in message queue individually? The messages will be displayed/viewed first to a dialog and then the next one after clicking ok/proceed and soon.

I would be using Thread and will just dynamically add a message to message queue.

I've follow this book,[click here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/efficient-android-threading/9781449364120/ch04.html) but could not find any to solve this

I have this code so far:

```
private static class LooperThread extends Thread {

    private String TAG = "LooperThread";

    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                if(msg.what == 0) {
                    doLongRunningOperation();
                    Log.e(TAG,"doLongRunningOperation - 0");
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG,"doLongRunningOperation - 1");
                }
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }

    private void doLongRunningOperation() {
        // Add long running operation here.
    }

}


btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mLooperThread.mHandler != null) {
                Message msg = mLooperThread.mHandler.obtainMessage(0);

                Message msg2 = mLooperThread.mHandler.obtainMessage(1);

                mLooperThread.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

                mLooperThread.mHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I pressed the btn, all messages will be printed.

Is there a best way to implement this technique?What do you recommend?

Comment: what exactle do you want to achieve?

Comment: The messages will be displayed in a dialog box, but the problem is in handlemessage, it loaded or showed all the messages that would make to display it all. I would want to achieve it as a one at a time display of messages in message queue.

Comment: so use a Queue: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html and remove() / poll() when showing the dialog

Comment: Yes, I will try to use it. I would like to share the process, there will be a thread whose task is to check if local db has data/new data and get that data and pass to the queue. Now to display the first data in that queue to a dialog, I would create another thread to this but, will be paused until button ok is pressed in the dialog to load the next data. is that a good way?